# How do i get resized image of external site?

Tags: php

I am trying to display resized images for thumbnail view in my website.

I am creating a page of gallery list where there will be list of thumbnails of images from external site. i.e if my images are located in xyz.com/images/abc.jpg [600 x 400] then i would  like to show its resized form of 150 x 100 in my website.

How much it is effective and good in case of performnance and bandwdith too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) will resize an image for ya, there are plenty of examples in the documentation/comments.

The fact that the source image is on another server just means you use a URL when creating the image resource:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpg("http://xyz.com/images/abc.jpg");
```

Store the thumbnail on your server and serve that file on future requests rather than generating it again on each request, otherwise you waste lots of bandwidth and CPU time.

Comment: You probably don't want to do that for every image every time someone visits your site. You'll be creating lots of unnecessary traffic from your site to their site, and extra load on your server. So use Dan's solution above, but put it into a scheduled job which will essentially generate cached content and smaller images for your site, perhaps once a day, maybe a bit more frequently if images on the other site change regularly.